# Error installing Py4j in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, py4j

I am not able to install Py4j in Anaconda - Spyder.

I am working on Windows 32bit, Python 3.5 and anaconda 4.1.

I get the following error:

[image]

I tried multiple commands including 
conda install py4j

I also run the following command:

```
C:\Users\360529>anaconda search -t conda py4j
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     Voskrese/py4j             |      0.9 | conda           | win-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     anaconda-cluster/py4j     |      0.9 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     ashahba/py4j              |   0.10.4 | conda           | linux-64
     auto/py4j                 |    0.8.1 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32

                                          : http://py4j.sourceforge.net/
     blaze/py4j                |      0.9 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     chdoig/py4j               |    0.8.1 | conda           | osx-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     conda-cluster/py4j        |  0.8.2.1 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     conda-forge/py4j          |   0.10.4 | conda           | linux-64, win-32,
win-64, osx-64
     hargup/py4j               |          | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     marciorf/py4j             |  0.8.2.1 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     mutirri/py4j              |  0.8.2.1 | conda           | linux-64
     quasiben/py4j             |   0.10.1 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
     sotera/py4j               |      0.9 | conda           | linux-64
                                          : Enables Python programs to dynamical
ly access arbitrary Java objects
     tapatk/py4j               |   0.10.4 | conda           | linux-64, win-64
Found 14 packages
```

It looks like Win-32bit version of 10.4 is available. But not sure why it is not installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are typing:

```
conda install -c blaze py4j=0.10.4
```

This will try to fetch the package py4j v0.10.4 from the anaconda channel `blaze`. But as you can see from the output for `anaconda search py4j`:

```
conda-forge/py4j  |  0.10.4 | conda | linux-64, win-32, win-64, osx-64
```

The `Win-32` version is available on the conda channel `conda-forge`. So you need to type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge py4j=0.10.4
```